# Alternative to UNION ALL for 2 tables with hardcoded values in each

Tags: mysql, typeorm

Is there an alternative to the query **without** using UNION ALL below?
I have 2 queries I joined together using UNION ALL but each query has a hardcoded value
to differentiate rows between the two.

'D' to signify if that row is from 'deposit' table, 'W' to signify if the row is from 'withdrawal' table

I use [typeorm](/questions/tagged/typeorm) which lacks a native way to express UNION or UNION ALL.

```
SELECT user_id, deposit.amount as Amount, YEAR(date_created) as Year, MONTHNAME(date_created) as Month, 'D' As 'Type' FROM deposit
UNION ALL
SELECT user_id, withdrawal.amount as Amount, YEAR(date_created) as Year, MONTHNAME(date_created), 'W' FROM withdrawal
```

Here is my expected output so far:

| user_id | amount | month | year | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | July | 2021 | D |
| 2 | 100 | August | 2021 | W |

Comment: This is the correct way to do it.

Comment: @forpas I was asking for an alternative WITHOUT using UNION ALL

Comment: @BreadBoard.ini why don't you want to use UNION ALL?

Comment: For the output that you want, which I assume is all the rows of both tables with an additional column and without anything else there is only UNION ALL.

Comment: I vote to close this question, as there is no problem statement.

Comment: @trincot Actually there is, I was planning to translate this query in TypeORM but there is no UNION ALL function in TypeORM

Comment: Why didn't you mention TypeORM in the first place? The way your question was written it sounded like a stupid professor trick ... a problem set with an artificial constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Your database has separate tables for deposit and withdrawal, and you're trying to display detailed (row-by-row) data from those tables *as if they were one table.*  SQL handles sets of rows, and your requirement is to present a set that's the union of two tables.

In SQL, UNION ALL is the way you do that.  Some uses of UNION ALL are gratuitous nonsense, but your use is on point.

If you need to present those tables as if they were one so an application (like yours based on TypeORM) can use them, create a view. Say something like this to your MySQL client program. It's like defining a table, you only need to do it once.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ledger AS
SELECT user_id, deposit.amount as Amount, 
       YEAR(date_created) as Year, MONTHNAME(date_created) as Month, 
       'D' As 'Type' FROM deposit
UNION ALL
SELECT user_id, withdrawal.amount as Amount, 
       YEAR(date_created) as Year, MONTHNAME(date_created), 
       'W' FROM withdrawal;
```

Then, in TypeORM you can refer to `ledger` as if it were a table.  You won't be able to insert or update it, but you can select data from it.

Don't worry too much about performance. MySQL's query planner is quite smart about accessing this kind of view efficiently.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, however I have not mentioned that I'm actually not allowed to alter my company's development database which I will try to run this solution on. Any alternatives?